# Javascript localStorage loop outputting only last item

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, local-storage

Hello i have problem with javascript for loop, i have 2 items in localStorage:

```
{"nazev":"1","sire":"2","mnozstvi":"3","barva":"4","typ":"5","slozeni":"6","strec":"7","poznamka":"8"}
{"nazev":"9","sire":"10","mnozstvi":"11","barva":"12","typ":"13","slozeni":"14","strec":"15","poznamka":"16"}
```

my code:

```
if(window.localStorage.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
        var foo = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
    }
    //con
    $('#nv').html(foo);
}
```

and html output (console.log is outputting both; but this not):

```
{"nazev":"9","sire":"10","mnozstvi":"11","barva":"12","typ":"13","slozeni":"14","strec":"15","poznamka":"16"}
```

if someone know why it's happening and how i can fix it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(window.localStorage.length > 0) {
    var foo = '';
    for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
        foo += localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
    }
    //con
    $('#nv').html(foo);
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The code is writing the last one as you asked it to, You can accumulate and then print; `foo +=`

```
if(window.localStorage.length > 0) {
    var foo ='';
    for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
       foo += localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
    }
    //con
    $('#nv').html(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, foo is taking the last value, you need to concatenate it inside for loop. I am assuming you have initialised foo earlier.

```
if(window.localStorage.length > 0) {
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
    var foo+ = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i)); //concate the string
}
    $('#nv').html(foo);
}
```